# Question from Einstein's original paper on special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

Just for fun, I started reading the original paper by Einstein on the special theory of relativity. Well, what do you know? I got stuck in a place because he jumped a few steps. See if anyone can help me. See the paste below. I would like to know how he gets from the first equation to the second one, after making the assumption that x’ is infinitesimally small.

From the paper

ON THE ELECTRODYNAMICS OF MOVING BODIES By A. EINSTEIN June 30, 1905

https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/specrel/specrel.pdf
on page 6.

From the origin of system k which is moving along x axis with velocity v wrt. the stationary system K, let a ray be emitted at the time τ0 along the X-axis to x’(which is a stationary point in k) , and at the time τ1 be reflected thence to the origin of the co-ordinates, arriving there at the time τ2; we then must have 1/2 (τ0 + τ2) = τ1, or, by inserting the arguments of the function τ and applying the principle of the constancy of the velocity of light in the stationary system K:—

1/2 ( τ (0, 0, 0, t) + τ ( 0, 0, 0, t + x’ / c − v) + x’/ (c + v)) = τ (x’, 0 , 0, t + x’/ (c − v)) ←—— from here

Hence, if x’ be chosen infinitesimally small,

1/2 (1/( c − v) + 1/( c + v))* ∂τ/∂t = ∂τ/∂x’+ (1/(c − v ))*∂τ/∂t ←—- to here .How???

Comment: What do you get if you Taylor expand the first relation around some point $t_0,x_0$ (and ignore terms that are second order or higher)?

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. Care to elaborate?